# Launching eclipse from command line with explicit vmargs ignores vmargs in eclipse.ini

Tags: eclipse

I have some vmargs that need to be added to a command line launcher of Eclipse, but when I do so, the vmargs that are in the eclipse.ini file are ignored.

For example, if I launch Eclipse like this:

```
eclipse -vmargs -Dmy.sys.prop=true
```

Then, Eclipse will launch with the JVM default settings for Xmx, Xms, and permgen space.  This means that Eclipse will quickly start thrashing memory and be unusable.

I know that I could copy all entries in eclipse.ini into a command line launcher, but I'd rather not do this (confusing and a pain for users).

How can I get an eclipse launch to respect both eclipse.ini and command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

skip the `-vmargs` if you want just system properties to be set.

eg : [image]

and what I get on the eclipse config matches with what I set in `eclipse.ini` .

[image]

Comment: Hmmm....that's not working for me.  I do see the argument in the configurations view, but the system property is not being found using System.getProperty().

Comment: You wouldn't get that because the property you set is for Eclipse and not for your program. If you want to access the property via `System.getProperty` go to "Run connfigurations" and then select yours and in the Arguments tab add the desired properties in VM Arguments.

Comment: The program I am running *is* eclipse.  I am trying to launch Eclipse with this particular system property so that the plugin I have written can access it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, not sure the dual thing you need is going to work. (either eclipse.ini or cmd line would work). This workaround I read some where. Have a wrapper script for your eclipse ( like eclipse_start.sh or something). In that set an env var and you can access the same env var from your plugin using `System.getenv`. Let me knwow whether that works.